# Messages added to ValidationSummary are only shown in ValidationSummary

Tags: blazor

I am having a simple form in a razor component with one input field called Name. If its empty an error messages are shown properly with validation done with data annotations. But I am also having a custom validation, but the message of this is only shown in the `ValidationSummary`, not in the `ValidationMessage`.

My code looks like this:

```
<EditForm EditContext="@_editContext">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
        <InputText id="countryCode" @bind-Value="_model.Name" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.Name)" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    class MyModel
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private EditContext _editContext;
    private MyModel _model = new MyModel();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(_model);

        var messages = new ValidationMessageStore(_editContext);

        _editContext.OnFieldChanged +=
            (sender, eventArgs) => ValidateFields((EditContext)sender, messages, eventArgs.FieldIdentifier);
    }

    private void ValidateFields(EditContext editContext, ValidationMessageStore messages, FieldIdentifier field)
    {
        messages.Clear();

        if (field.FieldName == nameof(_model.Name))
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_model.Name) && !char.IsUpper(_model.Name[0]))
            {
                messages.Add(editContext.Field(_model.Name), "Name should start with a capital.");
                editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I leave the field empty I get this:

[image]

If I enter a name wrongly, I get only this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just replace:

```
messages.Add(editContext.Field(_model.Name), "Name should start with a capital.");
```

with

```
messages.Add(() => _model.Name, "Name should start with a capital.");
```

Then it should work just fine.